# python: having trouble with an if statement that restarts a loop

Tags: python

I have:

```
for i in range(999):
    os.system('clear')player_hand1 = random.randint(2,11)

    player_hand2 = random.randint(2,11)
    dealer_hand1 = random.randint(2,11)
    dealer_hand2 = random.randint(2,11)
    player_hand_total = player_hand1 + player_hand2
    dealer_hand_total = dealer_hand1 + dealer_hand2

    if player_hand_total > 21:
       print("You broke!")
       time.sleep(3)
       continue
    else:
       print("Keep going")
```

I'm trying to have 2 random numbers add up to one number, and if that total is more than 21 then it restarts the loop. But my issue is that it restarts the loop even though the number is less than 21. Can someone help me out? If ya'll need the full code, I can post it here, it's not that long

Comment: What do you think `continue` does?  What do you think should happen in a loop when `continue` *isn't* used?

Comment: The variables `dealer_hand1`, `dealer_hand2` and `dealer_hand_total` seem to be unnecessary. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Suppose there were no `if` statement at all. Would you be surprised that it then restarts the loop every time? In your own words, what do you think is the purpose of a loop? What do you think *causes* a loop to "restart"? Where the code says `print("Keep going")`, exactly what do you think should happen next after that prints, and **why** do you think that should happen?

Comment: @ScottHunter youre right i just fixed it im stupid asf lmfaoo thanks a lot for putting that into perspective